# Backport .po file translations

Tags: version-control, localization, translation, gettext

I want to backport translations, so lets say I have master.po and v1.po, where master.po has more translations than v1.po (but also differing msgids).

So I want to update v1.po by copying all the translations from master.po where the msgid matches. But I do not want new msgids from master.po to be copied if that one does not exist in v1.po (Which is why i cannot use msgcat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use any CAT (Computer Aided Translation) Tool on the market that supports a TM (Translation Memory). Load your existing translations into the TM and auto translate the v1.po file with the TM.
OmegaT is open source and free. We use SDL Trados Studio, which is not free, but more powerful.

Comment: Used a similar strategy now, with Translation Memory of Poedit (`Catalog -> Automatically translate using TM`). I still had a lot of manual work, because it does fuzzy matching and I got a lot of unusable translations that I had to check manually.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Eazy Po](http://www.eazypo.ca), open master.po and then from the menu: Catalog |Update/ Merge from file; choose v1.po as reference file to update from.  The new (unwanted) messages in master.po will be shown as obsolete. When starting update; in Update options dialog and in Obsolete messages section; select remove. In Update options dialog you can also decide how to merge translation between the two files.

Comment: I could not try Eazy Po on my OS. +1 though, because this seems like a good way, in general.